# How can I connect to the wifi?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, however after the install, I couldn't see any network options. I checked to see if my network hardware was detected, it was, but I still can't connect to the internet. I am using a MacBook Air, and my wireless adapter model is bcm4360 802.11ac wireless network adapter by Broadcom.

Comment: You might need to put the wifi AP on a 2.4 GHz channel 1-11 rather than on auto

Comment: In which manner did you check if the network hardware was detected? Does it show up in the output of `ip addr`?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.